# Cannot disable non-SNI accesses to default SSL host

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, ssl

I am running here a multi-tenant web site with vhosts in Apache 2.4.10 in Jessie.

I am trying to disable the possibility of non-SNI clients to access (the default) SSL site.

For that I setup in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf`

```
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck On
```

From the file:

> SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck : Whether to forbid non-SNI clients to access
>   name based virtual hosts.

However, after restarting `apache`, non-SNI clients are still able to access the default SSL host.

For instance, this still works:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:443
```

Likewise, trying to access a vhost without SNI, using

```
openssl s_client -connect domain.com:443
```

still returns the default SSL domain, whist accessing the same host with SNI:

```
openssl s_client -connect domain.com:443 -servername domain.com
```

returns the appropriate page from the vhost.

I also tried putting the `SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck On` directive in the default SSL vhost to no avail.

Am I missing something obvious?